# when do getService() return null?

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I got a Widget(appwidgetprovider + service)

I use getService() in subthread like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, this.getClass());    
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);    
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAGS_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);      
intent.putExtra("test", test);    

Intent intent = new Intent(context, this.getClass());    
Integer requestCode = notDuplicateInteger;
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.test, pendingIntent, test);
```

this getService() sometimes return null;

But, I cannot understand when it has happend.

this null PendingIntent occurs the following Nullpointer Exception in updateAppWidget(provider, remoteView)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.RemoteViews$SetOnClickPendingIntent.writeToParcel(RemoteViews.java:436)
at android.widget.RemoteViews.writeToParcel(RemoteViews.java:1660)
at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1168)
at android.widget.RemoteViews$ViewGroupAction.writeToParcel(RemoteViews.java:903)
at android.widget.RemoteViews.writeToParcel(RemoteViews.java:1660)
at com.android.internal.appwidget.IAppWidgetService$Stub$Proxy.updateAppWidgetProvider(IAppWidgetService.java:485)
at android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetManager.java:341)
at android.test.TestService$HandlerCallback.boolean handleMessage(android.os.Message)(SourceFile:423)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

My Service extends Service.

I use AppWidgetProvider and ConfigureActivity(broadcast android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE).

ConfigureActivity does following.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);    
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)
```

Comment: you start your service like Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this, ServiceClassname.class);
startService(intent); Can you show us your class code. Does your class extend Service?

Comment: My Service extends Service. I use AppWidgetProvider and ConfigureActivity(broadcast android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE). ConfigureActivity does following `Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId); setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)`

Comment: Same to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776298/java-lang-nullpointerexception-long-baba1

Comment: Thank you nnnthuan. But, I need to use not getActivity() but getService(). Because I have to make PendingIntent for Reload RemoteView.

Comment: Probably,RemoteException is thrown in IBinder.transact() or Binder(ActivityManagerNative or ActivityManagerProxy).onTransact(). Consequently, PendingIntent is null. I can't understand reason which is thrown RemoteException