# java.lang.NullPointerException long baba1

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am sending `long` value and `String` value as extras from list activity to agenmin activity.But get `java.lang.NullPointerException` at `line 120`

```
    long baba1 = intent1.getExtras().getLong("baba",0); //line number 120
```

Sending from list activity

```
          // long id from from listview

            Intent i = new Intent(list.this, agenmin.class);
            i.putExtra("baba", id);
            startActivity(i); 

             //int position from listview
            String c= Integer.toString(position);
            Intent i1 = new Intent(list.this, agenmin.class);
            i1.putExtra("abc", c);
            startActivity(i1);
```

At receiving side agenmin

```
            Intent i1 = getIntent();
        String easyPuzzle;
        easyPuzzle=i1.getStringExtra("abc");
        textView2.setText(easyPuzzle);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position " + (mess)+" ROWID " +(easyPuzzle), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


           Intent intent1 = getIntent();
        long baba1 = intent1.getExtras().getLong("baba",0);
        String strLong1 = Long.toString(baba1);
        textView3.setText(strLong1);
```

**Logcat:**

```
      05-27 20:43:45.169: E/AndroidRuntime(593): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
      05-27 20:43:45.169: E/AndroidRuntime(593): java.lang.NullPointerException
      05-27 20:43:45.169: E/AndroidRuntime(593):    at com.indianic.demo.calendark.agenmin$1.onClick(agenmin.java:120)
```

I started the agenmin activity twice thats the reason for '`java.lang.NullPointerException` at `line 120`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have two intents starting the `agenmin` activity?

This way you're starting the `agenmin` activity twice, but giving only one extra to each of the starts. Then the second extra can't be obtained and it crashes when you try to use its value.

Just do this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(list.this, agenmin.class);
i.putExtra("baba", id);
i.putExtra("abc", c);
startActivity(i);
```

And I suggest you read more about what intents are and how they work. For example [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). For starting a different activity, you only need one intent. And you can put as many extras in it as you wish.

Comment: Are you sure that line 120 is really what you say it is? Because there doesn't seem to be anything that could cause a `NullPointerException`...

Comment: its because i started the activity two times it solved my problem.But if i initialized  long baba1=0; it stopped giving java.lang.NullPointerException but the app used to crash thank you!! :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

`PendingIntent intent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`